# Faster Way to write an Array to the Console?

Tags: c, arrays, printing, console, conways-game-of-life

I recently tried to make my own version of the Game of Life, and it works, the only problem is the printing to the Console, if you execute it you can clearly see that it writes from left to right, and takes about 0.3 seconds, and i would like it to be a little bit faster
If you want to compile it just enter a 0 on the first screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "console.h"
//#include <conio.h>

#define XSIZE 80 // max 240
#define YSIZE 25 // max 67

int clone(int array1[XSIZE][YSIZE], int array2[XSIZE][YSIZE]);
int print(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE]);
int getrandarray(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE]);
int countNachbar(int x, int y, int array[XSIZE][YSIZE]);
int calccells(int thisarray[XSIZE][YSIZE], int nextarray[XSIZE][YSIZE]);

int choice;

int main()
{
    setCursorType(0);
    srand(time(0));
    initConsole();
    //mode con: cols=XSIZE lines=YSIZE;
    int cells[XSIZE][YSIZE], nextcells[XSIZE][YSIZE] = {};
    int cellgen = 0;
    char c;
    printf("Nachbarmodus?\n1 = Rechteck(Randzellen bleiben immer gleich, stirbt nicht oft aus)\n0 = Torus(Die seiten des rechteckes werden verbunden, um einen Donut\ndarzustellen, der keine raender hat, stirbt oefter aus, ist der Originale Modus)\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(0, 0);
    getrandarray(cells);
    print(cells);
    while(c != 27)
    {
        calccells(cells, nextcells);                    //memcpy (cells, nextcells, YSIZE*XSIZE*sizeof(int));
        print(nextcells);
        cellgen++;
        gotoxy(0, YSIZE+1);
        printf("Generation %d", cellgen);
        clone(nextcells, cells);
        if(kbhit())
            c = getch();
    }
    return 0;
}

int print(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int x, y;
    for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
        {
            gotoxy(x, y);
            if(array[x][y] == 1)
                printf("%c", 254);
            else if(array[x][y] == 0)
                printf(" ");
        }
    }
}

int getrandarray(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int x, y;
    for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = rand()%2;
            //array[x][y] = 1;

        }
    }
}

int countNachbar(int x, int y, int array[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int sum=0, i, j, spalte, reihe;
    for(i=-1; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=-1; j<2; j++)
        {
            spalte = (x + i + XSIZE) % XSIZE;
            reihe = (y + j + YSIZE) % YSIZE;
            sum += array[spalte][reihe];
        }
    }
    sum-=array[x][y];
    return sum;
}

int clone(int array1[XSIZE][YSIZE], int array2[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int x, y;
    for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
        {
            array2[x][y] = array1[x][y];
        }
    }
}

int calccells(int thisarray[XSIZE][YSIZE], int nextarray[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int x, y, state, nachbarn;
    for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
        {
            state = thisarray[x][y];
            nachbarn = countNachbar(x, y, thisarray);
            if(state == 0 && nachbarn == 3)
            {
                nextarray[x][y] = 1;
            }
            if(state == 1 && (nachbarn < 2 || nachbarn > 3))
                nextarray[x][y] = 0;
            if(choice)
            {
                if(x == 0 || x == (XSIZE-1) || y == 0 || y == (YSIZE-1) )
                    nextarray[x][y] = thisarray[x][y];
            }

        }
    }

}


//console.h:
//https://www.mediafire.com/file/124e42w8mzy0o4z/console.h/file
//https://www.mediafire.com/file/89j8f9kf7ndyqp6/console.c/file
```

Comment: I'm also open to improvments to the already working code.

Comment: So you want it to write from right to left?

Comment: So what makes you think the problem is in the code and not in your MS DOS emulator? Emulators tend to be very slow. Do you get the same problem when you run it on a MS DOS computer? ("Where do I find a MS DOS computer?"  Good question!)

Comment: I don't run it on a emulator i run it in Codeblocks

Comment: I just want to write it very quickly

Comment: What is your platform/compiler/ide/OS/version/etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i used @Pimich 's advice, this is the code now, before the print command took about 0.8 seconds, now it takes 0.03s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define XSIZE 236 // max 236
#define YSIZE 61 // max (61)67
#define SLEEP 50

void print(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE]); // unused
void getrandarray(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE]);
void qprint(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE]);
int countNachbar(int x, int y, int array[XSIZE][YSIZE]);
void clone(int array1[XSIZE][YSIZE], int array2[XSIZE][YSIZE]); // unused
void calccells(int thisarray[XSIZE][YSIZE], int nextarray[XSIZE][YSIZE]);

int choice;

int main()
{
    setCursorType(0);
    srand(time(0));
    SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0 , 0 , XSIZE , YSIZE+5};
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), TRUE, &windowSize);
    int cells[XSIZE][YSIZE] = {}, nextcells[XSIZE][YSIZE] = {};
    int cycles = 0;
    char c;
    double timetaken, cpuTime, biggestCpuTime = 0;
    printf("Nachbarmodus?\n1 = Rechteck(Randzellen bleiben immer gleich, stirbt nicht oft aus)\n0 = Torus(Die seiten des rechteckes werden verbunden, um einen Donut\ndarzustellen, der keine raender hat, stirbt oefter aus, ist der Originale Modus)\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(0, 0);
    getrandarray(cells);
    qprint(cells);
    while(c != 27)
    {
        clock_t tic = clock();
        //measure time for 1 cycle
        calccells(cells, nextcells);
        qprint(nextcells);
        cycles++;
        memcpy (cells, nextcells, YSIZE*XSIZE*sizeof(int));
        if(kbhit())
            c = getch();
        delay(SLEEP);
        //Calculate Stats
        clock_t toc = clock();
        timetaken = (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cpuTime = timetaken-(SLEEP/1000.0);
        if(cpuTime > biggestCpuTime)
            biggestCpuTime = cpuTime;
        gotoxy(0, YSIZE+1);
        printf("Time per Cycle: %f s\nDelay:          %f s\nCPU Time:       %f s\nworst CPU Time: %f s\nCycle:          %d", timetaken, SLEEP/1000.0, cpuTime, biggestCpuTime, cycles);
    }
    return 0;
}

void qprint(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    char text[XSIZE*YSIZE+(YSIZE)];
    char at[2];
    *at = 254;
    char space[2] = " ";
    char newline[2] = "\n";
    text[0] = '\0';
    for(int j=0; j<YSIZE; j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<XSIZE; i++)
        {
            if(array[i][j] == 1)
                strcat(text, at);
            else
                strcat(text, space);
        }
        strcat(text, newline);
    }
    gotoxy(0, 0);
    printf("%s", text);
}

void print(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    gotoxy(0, 0);
    int x, y;
    for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
    {
        for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
        {
            if(array[x][y] == 1)
                printf("%c", 254);
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void getrandarray(int array[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int x, y;
    for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = rand()%2;
            //array[x][y] = 1;

        }
    }
}

int countNachbar(int x, int y, int array[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int sum=0, i, j, spalte, reihe;
    for(i=-1; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j=-1; j<2; j++)
        {
            spalte = (x + i + XSIZE) % XSIZE;
            reihe = (y + j + YSIZE) % YSIZE;
            sum += array[spalte][reihe];
        }
    }
    sum-=array[x][y];
    return sum;
}

void clone(int array1[XSIZE][YSIZE], int array2[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int x, y;
    for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
        {
            array2[x][y] = array1[x][y];
        }
    }
}

void calccells(int thisarray[XSIZE][YSIZE], int nextarray[XSIZE][YSIZE])
{
    int x, y, state, nachbarn;
    for(x=0; x<XSIZE; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<YSIZE; y++)
        {
            state = thisarray[x][y];
            nachbarn = countNachbar(x, y, thisarray);
            if(state == 0 && nachbarn == 3)
            {
                nextarray[x][y] = 1;
            }
            if(state == 1 && (nachbarn < 2 || nachbarn > 3))
                nextarray[x][y] = 0;
            if(choice)
            {
                if(x == 0 || x == (XSIZE-1) || y == 0 || y == (YSIZE-1) )
                    nextarray[x][y] = thisarray[x][y];
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing a quick profile of your code, I found that the functions taking up the most time are `gotoxy()` and `printf()`.

As such, I'd recommend you try to call those as little as possible.
So here's a list of improvements you can use:

- Since the grid starts at position (0, 0), you can simply call `gotoxy(0, 0);` at the beginning of `print()`.
- To reduce the number of calls to `printf()`, you can build a single string using your array. And then display that string with a single function call.
- For strings that are not formatted, you can use `puts()` rather than `printf()`.
- Alternatively, to print single characters, you can use `putc()`.

I hope this helps ! :)

Comment: Thanks! Will defintly try that.